# How to combine several binary variables into a new categorical variable

Tags: r

I am trying to combine several binary variables into one categorical variable. I have ten categorial variables, each describing tasks of a job.

Data looks something like this:

```
Personal_Help <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1)
PR <- c(2,1,1,2,1,2)
Fundraising <- c(1,2,1,2,2,1)
# etc.
```

My goal is to combine them into one variable, where the value 1 (=Yes) of each binary variable will be a seperate level of the categorical variable.

To illustrate what I imagine (wrong code obviously):

```
If Personal_Help = 1 -> Jobcontent = 1
If PR = 1 -> Jobcontent = 2
If Fundraising = 1 -> Jobcontent = 3
```

etc.

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit:
Thanks for your Answers and apologies for my late answer. I think more context from my side is needed. The goal of combining the binary variables into a categorical variable is to print them into one graphic (using ggplot). The graphic should display how many respondants report the above mentioned tasks as part of their work.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you want to handle cases where more than one of the inputs == 1? For example, if `Personal_Help == 1` and `Fundraising == 1`, what value should be assigned?

Comment: As it is possible for jobs to contain several tasks, they should be distinguishable. I don't know if this is useful but the idea would be:
If Personal Help ==1 ; Jobcontent ==1
If personal Help ==2; Jobcontent ==2
If Fundraising ==1; Jobcontent == 3
If Fundraising ==2; Jobcontent ==4

At least this is what I imagined would work. I edited my original post to explain why I am doing this in the first place. Maybe the whole task can be achieved much easier.

Answer (score 0):

As @ulfelder commented, you need to clarify how you want to handle cases where more than one column is `1`.

Assuming you want to use the *first* column equal to `1`, you can use `which.min()`, applied by row:

```
data <- data.frame(Personal_Help, PR, Fundraising)

data$Jobcontent <- apply(data, MARGIN = 1, which.min)
```

Result:

```
  Personal_Help PR Fundraising Jobcontent
1             1  2           1          1
2             1  1           2          1
3             2  1           1          2
4             1  2           2          1
5             2  1           2          2
6             1  2           1          1
```

If you’d like `Jobcontent` to include the *name* of each job, you can index into `names(data)`:

```
data$Jobcontent <- names(data)[apply(data, MARGIN = 1, which.min)]
```

Result:

```
  Personal_Help PR Fundraising    Jobcontent
1             1  2           1 Personal_Help
2             1  1           2 Personal_Help
3             2  1           1            PR
4             1  2           2 Personal_Help
5             2  1           2            PR
6             1  2           1 Personal_Help
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are three different variables, and each variable can take either of 2 values, there are 2^3 = 8 possible unique combinations of the three variables, each of which should have a unique number associated.

One way to do this is to imagine each column as being a digit in a three digit binary number. If we subtract 1 from each column, we get a 1 for "no" and a 0 for "yes". This means that our eight possible unique values, and the binary numbers associated with each would be:

```r
binary    decimal
0 0 0   = 0
0 0 1   = 1
0 1 0   = 2
0 1 1   = 3
1 0 0   = 4
1 0 1   = 5
1 1 0   = 6
1 1 1   = 7
```

This system will work for any number of columns, and can be achieved as follows:

```r
Personal_Help <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1)
PR <- c(2,1,1,2,1,2)
Fundraising <- c(1,2,1,2,2,1)
df <- data.frame(Personal_Help, PR, Fundraising)

New_var <- 0

for(i in seq_along(df)) New_var <- New_var + (2^(i - 1)) * (df[[i]] - 1)

df$New_var <- New_var
```

The end result would then be:

```
df
#>   Personal_Help PR Fundraising New_var
#> 1             1  2           1       2
#> 2             1  1           2       4
#> 3             2  1           1       1
#> 4             1  2           2       6
#> 5             2  1           2       5
#> 6             1  2           1       2
```

In your actual data, there will be 1024 possible combinations of tasks, so this will generate numbers for `New_var` between 0 and 1023. Because of how it is generated, you can actually use this single number to reverse engineer the entire row as long as you know the original column order.

Answer (score 0):

if you're interested only in the first occurrence of `1` among your variables:

```
df <- data.frame(t(data.frame(Personal_Help, PR,Fundraising)))
result <- sapply(df, function(x) which(x==1)[1])

X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 
 1  1  2  1  2  1
```

Of course, this will depend on what you want to do when multiple values are 1 as asked in comments.

Answer (score 0):

`max.col` may help here:

```
Jobcontent <- max.col(-data.frame(Personal_Help, PR, Fundraising), "first")
Jobcontent
#> [1] 1 1 2 1 2 1
```